# Gradle Settings File - extract funtions to separate files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Inside my projects I do something like following inside my `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
val libs_mine = "../../11 - libs (mine)"

# define my local custom libraries
val libraries = listOf(
    "Library1",
    "Library2",
    ...
)
# read a flag from my projects gradle.properties file
val useLiveDependencies = providers.gradleProperty("useLiveDependencies").get().toBoolean()

# if desired, I work with my local state of my libraries => this means I must include them...
if (!useLiveDependencies) {
    val projectFolders = libraries.map { "${libs_mine}/$it" }
    projectFolders.forEach {

        // 1) Root Folder
        val file = File(it)

        // 2) find all folders with a build.gradle.kts File (no root, no demo) => this returns me all modules
        val subProjectFolders = file.walkTopDown()
            .filter { it.isFile && it.name == "build.gradle.kts" }
            .map { it.parentFile }
            .filter { it != file }
            .filter { it.name != "demo" }

        println("Project = ${file.name}")

        // 3) include all the modules in this project
        subProjectFolders.forEach { project ->
            println("Sub Project = ${project.path}")
            val projectName = file.name
            val relativePath = project.relativeTo(file).path.split("\\", "-")
                .drop(1)
                .toMutableList()
                .also {
                    it.add(0, projectName)
                }.joinToString(":") {
                    it.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }
                }
            val path = ":$relativePath"
            //println("  path = $path")

            include(path)
            project(path).projectDir = project
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to extract the functionality into a separate file like following:

```kotlin
val libs_mine = "../../11 - libs (mine)"

# define my local custom libraries
val libraries = listOf(
    "Library1",
    "Library2",
    ...
)

# this file contains all the code that is missing from the above code block!
val commonFilesPath = "../../27 - settings"
apply(from = "../libraries.gradle.kts")
```

This fails, because the `applied` file can't access any of the setting variables - it fails instantly because it can't access `providers` e.g.

**Question**

First code block works - any idea how I could extract the functionality into a separate file that I can use in all my projects in common?